# Можно ли запретить отбрасывать ссылочную часть в typeid().name() ? C++

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Я хочу вывести в консоль полный тип переменной. Проблема в том, что typeid().name() выводит лишь базовый тип, отбрасывая модификаторы const и ссылочную часть. Можно ли как-то это поправить и вывести полностью например:

```
int x = 10;
const int& rx = x;
std::cout << typeid(rx).name() << std::endl; // Хочется, чтобы вывело const int&, а не int
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Напрямую нельзя. Можно сделать пустой шаблон а-ля `template <typename T> struct A {};`, и печатать имя `A<decltype(rx)>`.

---

Учитывайте, что `typeid(...).name()` возвращает красивое человеко-читаемое имя только в MSVC. В GCC и Clang вы получите mangled имя.

Поэтому более надежный способ вот такой:

```
template <typename T>
const char *TypeName()
{
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    return __FUNCSIG__;
    #else
    return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    #endif
}
```

На моем Clang-е, `TypeName<decltype(rx)>()` возвращает `const char *TypeName() [T = const int &]`.

Домашнее задание - научиться вынимать имя типа из возвращаемой строки, автоматически определяя сколько символов отбросить в начале и в конце.

На 5 с плюсом - делать это во время компиляции, чтобы лишние части строки не попадали в скомпилированную программу.

Comment: И от меня плюс за вопрос и за ответ