# Как узнать полный тип переменной в С++?

Tags: c++

Я использовал `typeid(var).name()`, но это выдает неполный тип. Например, вместо `const int&` - просто `int`. А мне нужно узнать полностью весь тип, включая модификаторы и другие атрибуты

Comment: Если в кратце, то typeid использует правила вывода типов, согласно им ссылочная часть и спецификаторы const отбрасываются. Вы можете сделать костыль, передавать тип в структуру, а ее в typeid. Я уже задавал похожий вопрос, возможно вы там найдете ответ подробнее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1331851/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-typeid-name-c/1331861#1331861

Comment: Отлично, заработало! Спасибо!